# Is it possible to obtain user's legal name from Coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

I seem to be unable to find neither relevant scope, nor API call to do that. The best matching one only returns user ID, not the real name. It also does not tell if user has verified Bio.

Comment: Wouldn't it be leaking client's privacy if Coinbase does expose such API?

Comment: @yongli1992 but user would have to explicitly consent to this scope in login dialog.